# How to validate Hibernate mapping against database

Tags: database, hibernate, orm

How to check that Hibernate mapping configuration matches database? I'd like know if I am using wrong version of hibernate mapping before I start executing update and queries, which then would fail.

I have bunch of classes that have been mapped with Hibernate annotations. I also have connection to corresponding database. Now I'd like to check if Hibernate mapping matches the database.

I'd like to  check at least following things:

- all mapped tables in Hibernate configuration have corresponding object in database (e.g table or view)
- all mapped fields exist in database
- all mapped fields have correct types

I'd prefer that I do not have to execute queries to mapped tables, preferably the check is based solely on database meta data.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [Hibernate configuration docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html):

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>
> e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

So, you can set it to `validate` and it will verify if everything in your hibernate mappings is present in the database. If you set it to `update`, then every time you add a mapped class or property, the underlying db schema will be updated to reflect that change.

You also have a command-line tool - [SchemaUpdate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaUpdate.html)

Comment: Something like that I am looking for. But is there something in API that I could execute programatically?

Comment: You can execute it programmatically.  Write a small program that creates a SessionFactory with "validate" turned on.

Comment: yes, there is a command line tool - I added it to my answer. Or preferably do what duffymo suggested.