# How to simulate a class change in an JPA integration test?

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm comparing the `javax.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel` object returned by `EntityManager.getMetamodel` at start of my application with a persisted instance which I store to a file using `XMLEncoder` at every shutdown of the application. The purpose is to detect changes to classes (which would result in different `Metamodel`s). The purpose is to warn the user that persistence is likely to fail because the schema needs to be modified or regenerated.

How could I simulate such a change in an integration test given the fact that:

- class loading doesn't support loading class X as class Y and thus I would need to define two classes in different projects. That would make me dependent on the build tool (e.g. `maven`)
- reflection doesn't allow removal of class fields and methods

I'm looking for a portable, i.e. cross-JPA provider solution, i.e. `hibernate`'s `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` isn't an option.

I'm using Java 7 with JPA 2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 with Linux 4.3.

Comment: I'm wondering, what is your goal really? "at start of the application" - did I understand it well, that you are duplicating test before every application start? Isn't it easier to just check some version field in DB? Do you want to check both - field added in DB, but not in class (not mapped) or only other way?

Comment: check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2116653/384674

Comment: @Betlista Maybe it's easier to check a version field. I would still have to generate the situation where a class is changed in my integration test and that's what my question is about. I could change the version field in the DB, but that would be cheating in an it. I don't want to check anything more than necessary to detect changes in classes in the database. The background is that I want a third party to be able to provide the entity model as well. I added note about `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in the question. Good call, though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase the question a little bit (please check, whether I missed something).

1. You have/want to write a component, that checks, that entity classes are in sync with database (whatever that means)
2. You are asking (basically), how to test such component

As I can see, you selected  the difficult path (class modification).

But if I understood your goal properly, why not to initialize DB in some state and run your component saying ok and in another test initialize DB in a different state to check, that your component found inconsistencies?