# How to prevent creating spring boot repository if table not exists?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Dears,

I have an application that connects two different data sources. I handled the data source connection based on the enable/disable property. But, I got a situation that there is a schema that exists but that does not contain the tables which are using my application.

I am wondering that my application is starting without any issue even table is not exists(I have not initialized Lazy anywhere). I didn't understand that why it's not failing while starting the application? But, it's failed when I tried to read the data with the exception of TABLE does not exist in SCHEMA.

I also need to know is there any possibility that we can load repository/bean if the table exists only? I hope someone might have faced similar issues when they are deploying in different regions.

Answer (score 0):

In the typical production setup JPA implementations (i.e. probably Hibernate or EclipseLink) won't do any checks to see if the schema matches their expectations.
I consider this a very reasonable default since in most setups the application doesn't really have any reasonable way to act when the schema is missing or broken.

You can activate validation, at least with Hibernate and I assume EclipseLink has something similar. [How to validate Hibernate mapping against database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116625/how-to-validate-hibernate-mapping-against-database)

But this will raise an exception and will abort the creation of an `EntityManager` and therefore stop the start of your application which does not seem what you want.

Controlling the injection of a repository seems difficult to achieve, but what you could do is to have a method in your repository, querying the data dictionary for the presence of a table and use that to control if the repository gets used.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. At present, I handled with ConditionalBean while creating/loading beans of each data source. I pass the condition value as false for the data source which does not have tables. Of course, this is not the dynamic solution and has to specify the property while starting the application and we should have an idea of tables exists or not in the given data sources. This way it even stopped loading the repositories of the data source while starting the application itself.